# Apache Ignite data loss when one node goes down

Tags: ignite

I'm new with Ignite and I'm trying to test data quality and availability of Ignite cluster.

I use the below xml configuration for setting cluster,

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="socketTimeout" value="50000" />
            <property name="networkTimeout" value="50000" />
            <property name="reconnectCount" value="5" />
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>x.x.x.1:47500..47509</value>
                            <value>x.x.x.2:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also and jthe CacheConfiguration is,

```
<bean id="cache-template-bean" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="CACHE_TEMPLATE*"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
                <property name="backups" value="1" />
             <!--   <property name="backups" value="2" />
                <property name="backups" value="3" /> -->
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL" />
                <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC" />
                <property name="rebalanceBatchSize" value="#{4 * 1024 * 1024}" />
                <property name="rebalanceMode" value="ASYNC" />
                <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true" />
                <property name="rebalanceBatchesPrefetchCount" value="4" />
                <property name="defaultLockTimeout" value="5000" />
                <property name="readFromBackup" value="true" />
                <property name="queryParallelism" value="6" />
                <property name="nodeFilter">
                 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.util.AttributeNodeFilter">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <map>
                                <entry key="ROLE" value="data.compute"/>
                            </map>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

My scenarios are,

1. Loaded the 5 million data when all the 3 nodes
2. Bring one node down
3. The count shows 3.75 million. (Data loss)
4. Bringing the node up counts 5 million again.

I tried backup 1,2,3 all resulted in the same data loss. As per Ignite documents, appears the data loss should not happen. If this fixed, I can try adding data when the node is down and check how it behaves.

Any suggestions, please?

Ash

Comment: Is persistance enabled? please show the full cache configuration including "nodeFilter"

Comment: Yes, persistence enabled in <property name="dataStorageConfiguration"> with <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>. Have updated the post with node filter

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of the baseline topology and persistence is to prevent unnecessary rebalance and store data only in specified server nodes. When a baseline node stopped, it is expected that one will back soon and the rebalance process is not triggered. You could exclude the node from the baseline using api or control.sh utility.

*IgniteCache.size()* returns the number of primary entries. So when a baseline node is stopped, *size()* shows a smaller number indicating that a number of primary entries is not accessible.

In your case the data is not lost by two reasons:
1. The data  is persisted in backup entries on alive baseline nodes.
2. The primary and backup entries located on the stopped node will back to the cluster after the node started.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology

Comment: control.sh utility remove node is resulting in data loss even after bringing the node up. I have used Cassandra and in Cassandra, there will not be any data loss when a node is down. The Gossiping will happen and the data will be available all the time. Thought ignite is such a kind of db.